# Rglpk Package (R) - Fantasy Sports Optimiser - Advanced Steps

Tags: r, linear-programming

I have a data frame (stats), which is structured as follows:

```
   Pos        Player.Name   TM   Sal  R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  R8  R9 R10 R11 R12 R16 R17 R18 R19 R20 R21 R22 R23     FP
1  MID        Blake Acres  STK 11200  83   0   0  41   0 126  49  35   0   0   0  71  32  65  46  91  82  99 121  66  71.92
2  FWD      Jack Billings  STK 12100  74  59 122 113  46  88  81  76  80   0  60   0   0  74  63  85  99  52 105  72  79.35
3  FWD         Josh Bruce  STK  9250  59  81  72  55  59  69  47  43 112  60  57  59  71  65  26  48 104  49  41  69  62.30
5  DEF      Sean Dempster  STK  8650  42  47  62  79  44  42  65  57  52  62  24   0  21  48  97  40  80  71  81  54  56.21
```

I can run a simple Rglpk lineup optimisation on this as follows with no issues at all and it will give me the optimal lineup based on stats$FP

```
num.players <- length(stats$Player.Name)
obj <- stats$FP
var.types <- rep("B", num.players)
names<-unique(stats$Player.Name)
mat<-matrix(0, nrow = length(names), ncol = nrow(stats))
for (i in 1:length(names)){mat[i,]<-as.numeric(stats$Player.Name == names[i])}
matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(stats$Pos == "DEF"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "MID"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "RK"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "FWD"),stats$Sal)
matrix<-rbind(mat,matrix)
direction <- c(rep("<=",length(names)),"==","==","==","==","<=") 
rhs <- c(rep(1,length(names)),2,4,1,2,100000)             
sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = matrix, dir = direction, rhs = rhs,types = var.types, max = TRUE)
Lineup<-stats[sol$solution==1,]
```

However, I want to modify this code so that I can find an optimal side which has met a specified score in a specified number of rounds (ie stats$R1 through stats$R23). I've put together a loop method which theoretically works but is just way too slow to be practicable:

```
target<-readline("Enter target score: ")
gms_target<-as.numeric(readline("Enter number of games to reach target score (out of 20): "))

pass<-"N"
avg<-2000

while (pass == "N"){
num.players <- length(stats$Player.Name)
obj <- stats$FP
var.types <- rep("B", num.players)
names<-unique(stats$Player.Name)
mat<-matrix(0, nrow = length(names), ncol = nrow(stats))
for (i in 1:length(names)){mat[i,]<-as.numeric(stats$Player.Name == names[i])}
matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(stats$Pos == "DEF"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "MID"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "RK"),as.numeric(stats$Pos == "FWD"),stats$Sal,stats$FP)
matrix<-rbind(mat,matrix)
direction <- c(rep("<=",length(names)),"==","==","==","==","<=","<=") 
rhs <- c(rep(1,length(names)),2,4,1,2,100000,avg)             
sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = matrix, dir = direction, rhs = rhs,types = var.types, max = TRUE)

Lineup<-stats[sol$solution==1,]
Salary<-sum(Lineup$Sal)
Score<-sum(Lineup$FP)
avg<-Score-.05
sums<-colSums(Lineup[,c(5:24)])
gms<-length(sums[sums >= target])
if(gms>=gms_target){pass="Y"}
}
```

Is there a simple way to build this request into the standard Rglpk framework?
For example, find the optimal lineup (based on stats$FP) where that team has scored 500 points in a minimum of 5 of the 20 games games between R1 and R23?

------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

I was thinking a little more about this and updating stats$FP from average score to total season score in the loop above drastically cuts down the loop run time, however, I'm still very interested in a non-loop alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the distribution functions in R. If you can find the mean and Standard deviation of your optimized teams, you could calculate the likelihood that a team would hit a specified score using pnorm(). I actually use it for my fantasy players to see what the likelihood is that they return a certain score for me. Here is an example of my code.

`players$lk = mapply(function(x,y,z) pnorm(q=z, mean=x, sd=y, lower.tail = FALSE), x=players$points, y=players$sd, z=players$projection)`

-players$points is their mean projection
-players$sd is their standard deviation 
-players$projection is number I want them to hit

You could use this same distribution function for your teams if you can calculate the standard deviation.